# ASP.NET GridView Browser Compatibility

Tags: asp.net, gridview, cross-browser

I use a `GridView` control which uses paging and inline editing. I am not using any other features (no sorting or anything fancy).

What browsers is this `GridView` control completely compatible with? Is there an "official" document/spec from MS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your site with http://browsershots.org/